# VBA inclusion when creating xls file with xlwt

Tags: python, excel, vba, python-3.x, xlwt

I tried searching for the answer to my question but most existing questions were mentioning editing an existing excel file. My question is, given that i have the VBA code that i would like to include in my excel file (it does not change/depend on what is in the excel file itself) is it possible to include it in the excel file created with xlwt? If so, how? 
I feel like the answer to this would be obvious but with my searching i couldn't find anything relevant. 
I am basically trying to avoid creating an excel file and then manually copy-pasting the code into the file (same applied to google sheets files)